# Ranges in Kotlin using data type Double

Tags: double, range, kotlin

If I try to compile this code...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (i in 1.0..2.0) {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

... I get the error saying

```
For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method
```

If I add a `step`...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (i in 1.0..2.0 step .5) {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

... then I get a new error instead:

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public infix fun CharProgression.step(step: Int): CharProgression defined in kotlin.ranges
public infix fun IntProgression.step(step: Int): IntProgression defined in kotlin.ranges
public infix fun LongProgression.step(step: Long): LongProgression defined in kotlin.ranges
public infix fun UIntProgression.step(step: Int): UIntProgression defined in kotlin.ranges
public infix fun ULongProgression.step(step: Long): ULongProgression defined in kotlin.ranges
```

How then can I use doubles in a range? The post [Ranges Reloaded](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/ranges-reloaded/) on The Kotlin Blog shows that using Double ranges is fine. I don't know what's wrong with mine.

Comment: Well that's a pretty weird thing to try, what should it even do? Enumerate all 4503599627370496 doubles between 1 and 2? That's a lot.

Comment: It seems like that functionality has been removed, and you'll have to use a `while` loop.

Comment: I meant to add step .5 to increment by .5 not every double between the two. Although I guess you can't use doubles in a range according to the documentation :/

Comment: `for (i in 2..4) { val j = 2.0 * i; ... }`

Answer (score 23):

As of Kotlin 1.1, a `ClosedRange<Double>` "cannot be used for iteration" ([`rangeTo()` - Utility functions - Ranges - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#rangeto)).

You can, however, define your own `step` [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) for this. e.g.:

```
infix fun ClosedRange<Double>.step(step: Double): Iterable<Double> {
    require(start.isFinite())
    require(endInclusive.isFinite())
    require(step > 0.0) { "Step must be positive, was: $step." }
    val sequence = generateSequence(start) { previous ->
        if (previous == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) return@generateSequence null
        val next = previous + step
        if (next > endInclusive) null else next
    }
    return sequence.asIterable()
}
```

Although you can do this if you are working with money you shouldn't really be using `Double` (or `Float`). See [Java Practices -> Representing money](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13).

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you can use `repeat` loop. For example in this situation you can count how many time this the loop will repeat. so...

```
fun main() {
    var startNum = 1.0
    repeat(4) {
        startNum += 0.5
        //TODO something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation for ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#rangeto):

> Floating point numbers (`Double`, `Float`) do not define their `rangeTo` operator, and the one provided by the standard library for generic Comparable types is used instead:

```
public operator fun <T: Comparable<T>> T.rangeTo(that: T): ClosedRange<T>
```

> The range returned by this function cannot be used for iteration.

You will have to use some other kind of loop since you can't use ranges.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(i in 0..2){
    var j=i.toFloat()*0.5+1.0f
    print(i)
}
```