# Why Kotlin doesn't have a Decimal Progression?

Tags: kotlin, bigdecimal

Recently I faced with a problem iterating through decimal numbers with a decimal step and I was wondered, why **Kotlin** has Progressions only for `Int`, `Long` and `Char`.

I understand, that there could be some caveats with decimal numbers. But still. We just want to have a start `BigDecimal` number, end `BigDecimal` number and then iterate through them with `BigDecimal` step.

> **Q:** So, why there is no any progressions for not integer numbers? Thank you.

*P.S.:* Here is a sample code of possible implementation (I took sources for Int and adapted to `BigDecimal`):

```
/**
 * Returns a progression that goes over the same range with the given step.
 */
public infix fun BigDecimalProgression.step(step: BigDecimal): BigDecimalProgression {
    if (step <= java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO) throw IllegalArgumentException("Step must be positive, was: $step.")
    return BigDecimalProgression.fromClosedRange(first, last, if (this.step > java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO) step else -step)
}

/**
 * A progression of values of type `BigDecimal`.
 */
public open class BigDecimalProgression
internal constructor
(
        start: BigDecimal,
        endInclusive: BigDecimal,
        step: BigDecimal
) : Iterable<BigDecimal> {
    init {
        if (step == BigDecimal.ZERO) throw kotlin.IllegalArgumentException("Step must be non-zero")
    }

    /**
     * The first element in the progression.
     */
    public val first: BigDecimal = start

    /**
     * The last element in the progression.
     */
    public val last: BigDecimal = getProgressionLastElement(start, endInclusive, step)

    /**
     * The step of the progression.
     */
    public val step: BigDecimal = step

    override fun iterator(): BigDecimalIterator = BigDecimalProgressionIterator(first, last, step)

    /** Checks if the progression is empty. */
    public open fun isEmpty(): Boolean = if (step > BigDecimal.ZERO) first > last else first < last

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
            other is BigDecimalProgression && (isEmpty() && other.isEmpty() ||
                    first == other.first && last == other.last && step == other.step)

    override fun hashCode(): Int =
            if (isEmpty()) -1 else (31 * (31 * first.hashCode() + last.hashCode()) + step.hashCode())

    override fun toString(): String = if (step > BigDecimal.ZERO) "$first..$last step $step" else "$first downTo $last step ${-step}"

    companion object {
        /**
         * Creates BigDecimalProgression within the specified bounds of a closed range.

         * The progression starts with the [rangeStart] value and goes toward the [rangeEnd] value not excluding it, with the specified [step].
         * In order to go backwards the [step] must be negative.
         */
        public fun fromClosedRange(rangeStart: BigDecimal, rangeEnd: BigDecimal, step: BigDecimal): BigDecimalProgression = BigDecimalProgression(rangeStart, rangeEnd, step)
    }
}

fun getProgressionLastElement(start: BigDecimal, end: BigDecimal, step: BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
    if (step > BigDecimal.ZERO) {
        return start + BigDecimal(((end - start) / step).toInt()) * step
    } else if (step < BigDecimal.ZERO) {
        return start - BigDecimal(((start - end) / -step).toInt()) * -step
    } else {
        throw kotlin.IllegalArgumentException("Step is zero.")
    }
}

/** An iterator over a sequence of values of type `BigDecimal`. */
public abstract class BigDecimalIterator : Iterator<BigDecimal> {
    override final fun next() = nextBigDecimal()

    /** Returns the next value in the sequence without boxing. */
    public abstract fun nextBigDecimal(): BigDecimal
}

/**
 * An iterator over a progression of values of type `BigDecimal`.
 * @property step the number by which the value is incremented on each step.
 */
internal class BigDecimalProgressionIterator(first: BigDecimal, last: BigDecimal, val step: BigDecimal) : BigDecimalIterator() {
    private val finalElement = last
    private var hasNext: Boolean = if (step > BigDecimal.ZERO) first <= last else first >= last
    private var next = if (hasNext) first else finalElement

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = hasNext

    override fun nextBigDecimal(): BigDecimal {
        val value = next
        if (value >= finalElement) {
            if (!hasNext) throw kotlin.NoSuchElementException()
            hasNext = false
        }
        else {
            next += step
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your question is better suited for https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP

Comment: @JoachimRohde thank you. I will try to add it there. However I thought, that there was a reason to not adding such functionality, thus I would be pointed to concrete caveats and would find another solution for my problem.

Comment: Bear in mind that floating-point arithmetic doesn't always work that simply. For example, it would be possible to construct infinite loops this way.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, could you please, provide an example of `start`, `end` and `step` values for "infinite loops" case?

Comment: For single precision, anything where the endpoints are at least 2^24 times bigger than the step size. At that point, incrementing by the step size would have no effect.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth as I know that is true for floats and doubles. Does it true for a BigDecimals?

Comment: Indeed, doubles encounter the same problem (at 2^53 rather than 2^24).  As far as I'm aware, the problem shouldn't occur for BigDecimal.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree with you. But my general question was about BigDecimals. Sorry, if I designed it wrong :(

Comment: With floating point numbers, there can also be some cases where `step * n` lies within the range, but `(1..n).map { step }.sum()` does not, due to the rounding. Therefore it's not clear how to handle these corner cases. This, however, is not a problem with `BigDecimal`.

Comment: See also [Ranges in Kotlin using data type Double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44315977/3255152).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it said in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#rangeto) for ranges:

> Floating point numbers (Double, Float) do not define their rangeTo
>   operator, and the one provided by the standard library for generic
>   Comparable types is used instead:

```
public operator fun <T: Comparable<T>> T.rangeTo(that: T): ClosedRange<T>
```

> The range returned by this function cannot be used for iteration. You
>   will have to use some other kind of loop since you can't use ranges.

They simply **do not define**.