# How to make a traditional for-loop in Kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

**JavaScript**

```
for (var x = 0; x < 360; x += 0.5)
{
  // ...
}
```

How do I do this in **Kotlin**?

---

Note that my step size is a floating point and so a regular range won't work:

```
for (x in 0.0 until 360.0 step 0.5) {
  // ...
}
```

I also need to exclude the ending value, hence why I'm using `until`.

---

I will resort to a while loop for now:

```
var x = 0.0;

while (x < 360.0) {
  // ...
  x += 0.5
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ranges in Kotlin using data type Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315977/ranges-in-kotlin-using-data-type-double)

Comment: That may not be an exact duplicate since it demonstrates a solution for a _closed_ range where you appear to want to exclude the end value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this right now in Kotlin because Kotlin does not have "traditional" `for` loops. I believe you're right in choosing a `while` loop. In fact, traditional `for` loops are just `while` loops in disguise:

```
for (init; condition; post;) {
    // do something
}
```

can always be rewritten,

```
init
while (condition) {
    // do something
    post
}
```

with no change in behavior, because the init statement will always execute and the condition will always be checked before the loop runs even once. One thing this construct can't give you is a variable that's only scoped to this block. If you're really after that behavior, the following would work, though it's not very idiomatic.

```
for (x in generateSequence(0.0) { it + 0.5 }.takeWhile { it < 360.0}) {
    println(x)
}
```

If you're using a Sequence, you might also be interested in the more idiomatic `forEach`:

```
generateSequence(0.0) { it + 0.5 }.takeWhile { it < 360.0 }.forEach { x ->
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This is actually ridiculous that Kotlin can't do a simple for loop. I'll use the while loop for now but I don't like the verbosity. The scoping isn't the end of the world. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DavidCallanan Just a bit curious, what are you using the for loop for that you need a non-integer range?

Comment: I'm looping over all angles between 0 degrees and 360 degrees with a given step

Answer (score 3):

As repeated addition is just a shorthand for multiplication you can look at `for (x in 0.0 until 360.0 step 0.5)` as "do something for as many times as `0.5` fits in `360`". Therefore it would make sense to express it like this:

```
val times = (360 / 0.5).toInt()
repeat(times){

}
```

of cause you can also inline times to

```
repeat(times = (360 / 0.5).toInt()){

}
```

The advantage is that you skip the sequence generation. Con -- you lose the access to your counting variable x.

see also https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Answer by @AdamYakes. 
Since the `until` operator is not available for Floating value type, you can not use 
it for floating `step` value.

However, If you still want to use

```
for (x in 0.0 until 360.0 step 0.5) {
  // use value
}
```

you can do that as following:

```
for (x in 0 until 3600 step 5) {
  // use (value / 10)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works if I know what the step is, but in my case the step is passed into my function so this would get more complicated.

Comment: Agreed. I just thought this is also an approach if you know what `step` value is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is so flexible that one could hack a custom solution:

```
private infix fun (((Double) -> Unit, Double) -> Unit).step(step: Double) = 
    fun(action: (Double) -> Unit) = this(action, step)
    
private infix fun Double.upto(to: Double) =
    fun(action: (Double) -> Unit, step: Double) { 
        var v = this
        while (v < to) {
            action(v)
            v += step
        }
    }

fun main() {
    // Usage:
    (0.0 upto 360.0 step 0.5) { 
        println(it)
    }
}
```

What I did above is to create two infix functions.

The `upto()` infix function can be used with two `Double`s: it takes `0.0 upto 360.0` and returns a function that expects two arguments: an `action` function and the `step` double value.

The `step` infix function can be used with functions returned by `upto()` combined with a `Double` (so `f step 0.5`). It returns a function that calls the `upto()` function passing the `step` value and the user's `{ ... }` block that gets called for each iteration.

Short and convoluted.

A simpler alternative:

```
inline fun doubleFor(
  from: Double, to: Double, step: Double, action: (Double) -> Unit
) {
    var v = from
    while (v < to) {
        action(v)
        v += step
    }
}

fun main() {
    // Usage:
    doubleFor(0.0, 360.0, 0.5) { 
        println(it)
    }
}
```

A good IDE would show the argument names next to the values making the meaning of the arguments in the usage code obvious.

A third approach can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332139/2933899 which allows one to write `for(x in 0.0 .. 360.0 step 0.5) { println(x) }` with the inconvenience that the top boundary value is included.

Run these at https://pl.kotl.in/ZuR354Fas